# Derive from class declared in private scope

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, inner-classes

I am currently refactoring some legacy code and would like to factorize a multiple if...elseif... statement into a series of classes implementing various strategies.

Since I have to access the original object's internals, I'm going to declare the new classes as nested classes; since nobody from the external world should access them, I'd prefer to declare them in private scope.

For the sake of exposing as few implementation details as possible, I was wondering whether it's possible to only forward-declare the base strategy class in the header file, and place all subclasses declaration in the implementation file. Code example as follows:

-- header file

```
class MyUglyClass
{
private:
    class IStrategyBase;
    IStrategyBase* sPtr;
    // class ActualImplementation; // this is what I'd like to avoid
    // class YetAnotherImplementation; // as above
    // blah blah blah
};
```

-- implementation file

```
class MyUglyClass::IStrategyBase
{
    virtual ResultType DoSomething(SomeType someParameter) = 0;
    // could expose some MyUglyClass members, since 
    // derived classes wouldn't inherit friendship
};

class ActualImplementation: public MyUglyClass::IStrategyBase
{
    ResultType DoSomething(SomeType someParameter) override
    {
        // Do actual work
    }
}

class YetAnotherImplementation: public MyUglyClass::IStrategyBase
{
    ResultType DoSomething(SomeType someParameter) override
    {
        // Doing something really tricky & clever for corner cases
    }
}
```

Of course the compiler complains since `IStrategyBase` is not accessible; I could work around this by fwd-declaring `ActualImplementation` and `YetAnotherImplementation` into the header file together with `IStrategyBase`, but I'd rather avoid this, since I would need to change the header if a new strategy was needed.

I could also declare `IStrategyBase` in public scope, however I would prefer to keep it private to avoid other people messing with it.

Of course I'm assuming that non-fwd-declared subclasses wouldn't inherit friendship with `MyUglyClass`, so I would have to expose relevant data the `IStrategyBase` protected members.

Is there any way to achieve this I could be missing?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to all folks who commented, I realized that nobody could mess with `IStrategyBase` class even if declared in public scope, since class definition would be buried in the implementation file as well. What I'm wondering now is if I could make derived classes access internals of `MyUglyClass` without having to fwd declare them together with `IStrategyBase`. I guess answer is "no", since friendship is not inherited, but perhaps there is some more C++ perk I'm missing.

Comment: Even if you declare `IStrategyBase` public, nobody can mess with it.

Comment: In my understanding, other people could derive from it. If `IStrategyBase` was exposing some `MyUglyClass` implementation details, they would then be accessible by anybody.

Comment: You cannot derive from a class that's only declared, and not defined.

Comment: Instead of giving away your possible solution & make us to derive the actual problem followed by solution, It will be great if you can provide the actual problem itself. i.e. what kind of "if, else if" you want to refactor. Need not give the complete code, but give some minimal part.

Comment: 1) You do not have the word `friend` in the code example. 2) Which line generates an error? The header looks OK and the implementation needs *definiton* of IStrategyBase.

Comment: @Vorac nested class are automatically friend in C++. I'm defining IStrategyBase at the beginning of implementation file

Comment: @Sam thanks for the insight, I was missing that point

Comment: Make the declaration public. The implementation is private, anyway.

Comment: @iammilind the actual problem is not that hard to solve, but I'm trying to deepend my knowledge of C++, hence this question. Given that nobody can inherit my class if the definition is only provided in the implementation file, I'm wondering whether I can give subclasses full access to `MyUglyClass` without fwd declaring them as well

Comment: Does `IStrategyBase` need to be a member of `MyUglyClass`?  You can always add `IStrategyBase` to  a namespace named `detail`.  SOP is that one does not use anything in that namespace unless they are the implementer.

Comment: @NathanOliver declaring in internal scope would provide it full access to `MyUglyClass` internals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility (this is not the pimpl idiom, just an accessibility hack):

```
class MyUglyClass
{
private:
    struct Impl; // Is automatically "friend struct Impl;"
    class IStrategyBase;
    IStrategyBase* sPtr;
    // class ActualImplementation; // this is what I'd like to avoid
    // class YetAnotherImplementation; // as above
    // blah blah blah
};

class MyUglyClass::IStrategyBase
{
public:
    virtual int DoSomething(int someParameter) = 0;
    // could expose some MyUglyClass members, since 
    // derived classes wouldn't inherit friendship
};

struct MyUglyClass::Impl
{
    class ActualImplementation: public MyUglyClass::IStrategyBase
    {
        int DoSomething(int someParameter) override
        { (void) someParameter; return 1;}
    };

    class YetAnotherImplementation: public MyUglyClass::IStrategyBase
    {
        int DoSomething(int someParameter) override
        { (void) someParameter; return 2; }
    };
};

int main() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to conceal any imlementation details you can use pImpl idiom (pointer to implementation) aka Opaque pointer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer So you can change your code like this

-- header file

```
#include <memory>

class MyUglyClass
{
    MyUglyClass();
    ~MyUglyClass(); // destructor must be only declared to avoid problems
                    // with deleting just forwarded inner class
private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> pImpl;
};
```

-- implementation file

```
class MyUglyClass::Impl
{
    class IStrategyBase;
    IStrategyBase* sPtr;
    class ActualImplementation; // now these classes safely hidden inside .cpp 
    class YetAnotherImplementation; // Nobody can reach them.

};

class MyUglyClass::Impl::IStrategyBase
{
    virtual ResultType DoSomething(SomeType someParameter) = 0;
    // could expose some MyUglyClass members, since 
    // derived classes wouldn't inherit friendship
};

class ActualImplementation: public MyUglyClass::Impl::IStrategyBase
{
    ResultType DoSomething(SomeType someParameter) override
    {
        // Do actual work
    }
};

class YetAnotherImplementation: public MyUglyClass::Impl::IStrategyBase
{
    ResultType DoSomething(SomeType someParameter) override
    {
        // Doing something really tricky & clever for corner cases
    }
};

MyUglyClass::MyUglyClass() : pImpl(new Impl()) {}

MyUglyClass::~MyUglyClass() {} // let the unique_ptr do its work
```